# Improve performance of SQL MIN+GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, min

I'm trying to improve on a very slow query.

Basically from a list of affiliate products I need to select the cheapest for each datafeed matching a (boolean)search query

The query works as expected but takes a long time (2+ sec) on a 1.5mil rows table

```
select p.* from  (
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    products a
WHERE
   display_price = (
            SELECT 
                MIN(display_price)
            FROM
                products b
            WHERE
                b.datafeed_id = a.datafeed_id
            AND 
                (match(b.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2" -women* -kid* -junior*' in boolean mode))
           )
AND
    (match(a.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2" -women* -kid* -junior*' in boolean mode))
group by 
    a.datafeed_id
)  
as p
where  
p.is_custom = 0
order by 
p.datafeed_id 
limit 50
```

Could you please help me to improve it?

I tried experimenting with INNER JOIN but i always get wrong results (not the cheapest products as expected)

TABLE DATA EXAMPLE

```
+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
| id        | mykey                   | merchant_name | model_number | name                                                                                      | description                                       | thumb_url                                                                                               | image_url                                                                                                                                                          | deep_link                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | delivery_time | in_stock | rrp_price | display_price | is_preorder | delivery_cost | created_at          | updated_at          | datafeed_id | category              | subcategory                                                  | is_custom | is_manual | autoslug                                                                          | category_id | sub_category_id | network_product_key | ws_api_key | used_price | userfield1 | userfield2 | userfield3 | userfield4 | api_refresh_failures | api_keywords                  |
+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
| 209322441 | 32_15724                | JackRabbit    | 609465417986 | Men's Altra Solstice Running Shoe - Color: Grey/Orange (Regular Width) - Size: 8.5        | Solstice Running Shoe                             |                                                                                                         | https://cdn.jackrabbit.com/media/catalog/product/m/e/mens-altra-solstice-running-shoe-color-greyblue-regular-width-size-7-609465332132-01.2351_1.jpg               | https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=bXlQtQGle9o&offerid=445404.15724&type=15&murl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jackrabbit.com%2Fmen-s-altra-solstice-running-shoe-afm1836-2.html                                                                  |               |        0 |      0.00 |         89.95 |           0 |          0.00 | 2019-08-13 07:00:43 | 2019-08-13 07:00:43 |          32 | Apparel & Accessories | Shoes~~Athletic Shoes & Sneakers~~Sneakers~~Running Shoes    |         0 |      NULL | men-s-altra-solstice-running-shoe-color-grey-orange-regular-width-size-8-5        |    24746552 |        24746581 | NULL                | NULL       |       NULL |            |            |            |            |                    0 | NULL                          |
| 209444684 | 17_887687492430         | NewBalance    | 887687492430 | New Balance 4128 Men's Momentum Long Sleeve - Cobalt Blue (MRT4128CBT)                    | New Balance 4128 Men's Momentum Long Sleeve       |                                                                                                         | http://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/NB/mrt4128cbt_nb_60_i?$google$                                                                                                     | https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=bXlQtQGle9o&offerid=691495.887687492430&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Ftracking.searchmarketing.com%2Fclick.asp%3Faid%3D172000630002315714                                                              |               |        0 |      0.00 |         36.99 |           0 |          0.00 | 2019-08-13 07:02:37 | 2019-08-13 07:02:37 |          17 | Men                   | Apparel~~Long Sleeve Shirts~~Running                         |         0 |      NULL | new-balance-4128-men-s-momentum-long-sleeve-cobalt-blue-mrt4128cbt-               |    24747216 |        24747104 | NULL                | NULL       |       NULL |            |            |            |            |                    0 | NULL                          |
| 210677909 | amazon-co-uk_B07JKJVNWS | amazon.co.uk  | NULL         | New Balance Women's 1500v4 Boa Running Shoes                                              | New Balance Women's 1500v4 Boa Running Shoes      | https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41nngdBxrmL._SL75_.jpg                                 | https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41nngdBxrmL.jpg                                                                                                   | https://www.amazon.co.uk/New-Balance-Womens-1500v4-Running/dp/B07JKJVNWS?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ2HRNZ42ECGURRQQ&tag=runshogur-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B07JKJVNWS                                             | NULL          |        1 |      NULL |         55.93 |        NULL |          NULL | 2019-08-15 14:13:42 | 2019-08-15 14:13:42 |          41 | NULL                  | NULL                                                         |         0 |      NULL | new-balance-women-s-1500v4-boa-running-shoes                                      |        NULL |            NULL | B07JKJVNWS          | amazon-co- |       0.00 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |                    0 | new balance 1500v4 women shoe |
| 209491456 | 17_889516760314         | NewBalance    | 889516760314 | New Balance 61021 Men's Trinamic Short Sleeve Top - Red/Black (MT61021AMH)                | New Balance 61021 Men's Trinamic Short Sleeve Top |                                                                                                         | http://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/NB/mt61021amh_nb_40_i?$google$                                                                                                     | https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=bXlQtQGle9o&offerid=691495.889516760314&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Ftracking.searchmarketing.com%2Fclick.asp%3Faid%3D172000630001018890                                                              |               |        0 |      0.00 |         74.99 |           0 |          0.00 | 2019-08-13 07:02:51 | 2019-08-13 07:02:51 |          17 | Men                   | Clothing~~Short Sleeve & Sleeveless Shirts~~Performance      |         0 |      NULL | new-balance-61021-men-s-trinamic-short-sleeve-top-red-black-mt61021amh-           |    24747216 |        24747297 | NULL                | NULL       |       NULL |            |            |            |            |                    0 | NULL                          |
| 209704762 | 38_332299573            | SportChek     | 332299573    | Under Armour Men's ColdGear Reactor Shorts                                                | Under Armour Menâ€™s ColdGear Reactor Shorts      | https://fgl.scene7.com/is/image/FGLSportsLtd/332299564_01_a?hei=800&wid=800&resMode=sharp2&op_sharpen=1 | https://fgl.scene7.com/is/image/FGLSportsLtd/332299564_01_a?hei=800&wid=800&resMode=sharp2&op_sharpen=1                                                            | https://www.pntra.com/t/Qz9HRURIP0NGS0pCQz9HRURI?website=250687&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsportchek.affiliatetechnology.com%2Fredirect.php%3Fnt_id%3D2%26url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.sportchek.ca%2Fproduct%2F332299564.html%23332299564%3D332299573 |               |        0 |      0.00 |         43.88 |           0 |          0.00 | 2019-08-13 07:04:39 | 2019-08-13 07:04:39 |          38 |                       |                                                              |         0 |      NULL | under-armour-men-s-coldgear-reactor-shorts                                        |          -1 |              -1 | NULL                | NULL       |       NULL |            |            |            |            |                    0 | NULL                          |
| 209323700 | 32_18027                | JackRabbit    | 609465418261 | Men's Altra Lone Peak 4.0 Trail Running Shoe - Color: Black/Red (Regular Width) - Size: 9 | Lone Peak 4.0 Trail Running Shoe                  |                                                                                                         | https://cdn.jackrabbit.com/media/catalog/product/m/e/mens-altra-lone-peak-4.0-trail-running-shoe-color-greyorange-regular-width-size-14-609465354726-01.2544_1.jpg | https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=bXlQtQGle9o&offerid=445404.18027&type=15&murl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jackrabbit.com%2Fmen-s-altra-lone-peak-4-0-trail-running-shoe-afm1855f-21.html                                                     |               |        0 |      0.00 |        119.95 |           0 |          0.00 | 2019-08-13 07:00:44 | 2019-08-13 07:00:44 |          32 | Apparel & Accessories | Shoes~~Athletic Shoes & Sneakers~~Sneakers~~Running Shoes    |         0 |      NULL | men-s-altra-lone-peak-4-0-trail-running-shoe-color-black-red-regular-width-size-9 |    24746552 |        24746581 | NULL                | NULL       |       NULL |            |            |            |            |                    0 | NULL                          |
| 209370278 | 17_887057044573         | NewBalance    | 887057044573 | Cobb Hill Poppy Women's Shop All Shoes - Black (CAG10BK)                                  | Cobb Hill Poppy Women's Shop All Shoes            |                                                                                                         | http://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/NB/cag10bk_ch_02_i?$google$                                                                                                        | https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=bXlQtQGle9o&offerid=691495.887057044573&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Ftracking.searchmarketing.com%2Fclick.asp%3Faid%3D172000630000396733                                                              |               |        0 |      0.00 |         89.99 |           0 |          0.00 | 2019-08-13 07:02:13 | 2019-08-13 07:02:13 |          17 | Women                 | Shoes~~Casuals~~Cobb Hill By New Balance~~Shop All Cobb Hill |         0 |      NULL | cobb-hill-poppy-women-s-shop-all-shoes-black-cag10bk-                             |    24746991 |        24747059 | NULL                | NULL       |       NULL |            |            |            |            |                    0 | NULL                          |
| 210680592 | amazon-co-uk_B07DRMQGC7 | amazon.co.uk  | NULL         | Brooks Men's Addiction 13 Running Shoes                                                   | Brooks Men's Addiction 13 Running Shoes           | https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2Bqhn33SVL._SL75_.jpg                               | https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2Bqhn33SVL.jpg                                                                                                 | https://www.amazon.co.uk/Brooks-Mens-Addiction-Running-Shoes/dp/B07DRMQGC7?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ2HRNZ42ECGURRQQ&tag=runshogur-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B07DRMQGC7                                           | NULL          |        1 |      NULL |        193.69 |        NULL |          NULL | 2019-08-15 14:34:47 | 2019-08-15 14:34:47 |          41 | NULL                  | NULL                                                         |         0 |      NULL | brooks-men-s-addiction-13-running-shoes                                           |        NULL |            NULL | B07DRMQGC7          | amazon-co- |       0.00 | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |                    0 | brooks addiction 13 men shoe  |
| 209522750 | 17_889116380196         | NewBalance    | 889116380196 | 574 Hook and Loop Kids' Infant Lifestyle Shoes - Blue, Black, Orange (KG574MTI)           | 574 Hook and Loop Kids' Infant Lifestyle Shoes    |                                                                                                         | http://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/NB/kg574mti_nb_14_i?$google$                                                                                                       | https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=bXlQtQGle9o&offerid=691495.889116380196&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Ftracking.searchmarketing.com%2Fclick.asp%3Faid%3D172000630000618712                                                              |               |        0 |      0.00 |         44.99 |           0 |          0.00 | 2019-08-13 07:03:01 | 2019-08-13 07:03:01 |          17 | Kids                  | Boys Shoes~~Infant (size 2 - 5, 5.5 - 10)~~Infant Lifestyle  |         0 |      NULL | 574-hook-and-loop-kids-infant-lifestyle-shoes-blue-black-orange-kg574mti-         |    24747441 |        24747457 | NULL                | NULL       |       NULL |            |            |            |            |                    0 | NULL                          |
| 209401692 | 17_887057216642         | NewBalance    | 887057216642 | Aravon Pauline-AR Women's by New Balance Shoes - Black (AAZ11BK)                          | Aravon Pauline-AR Women's by New Balance Shoes    |                                                                                                         | http://s7d5.scene7.com/is/image/NB/aaz11bk_ara_02_i?$google$                                                                                                       | https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=bXlQtQGle9o&offerid=691495.887057216642&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Ftracking.searchmarketing.com%2Fclick.asp%3Faid%3D172000630000635005                                                              |               |        0 |      0.00 |        249.99 |           0 |          0.00 | 2019-08-13 07:02:23 | 2019-08-13 07:02:23 |          17 | Women                 | Shoes~~Casuals~~Aravon By New Balance                        |         0 |      NULL | aravon-pauline-ar-women-s-by-new-balance-shoes-black-aaz11bk-                     |    24746991 |        24747102 | NULL                | NULL       |       NULL |            |            |            |            |                    0 | NULL                          |
+-----------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------------+-------------------------------+
10 rows in set (1.17 sec)
```

THANK YOU

Comment: At first glance, I suggest extracting the expensive match statement to `CTE`, including the `is_custom` filter. How about the INNER JOIN variant? Which indices did you set? Please provide a DB-Fiddle or a Table dump with a considerable amount of data for further analysis.

Comment: `SELECT *` is an improper use of `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

@giulio Your solution seems to be quite effective. Maybe a `covering index` will speedup a bit more.

If you are on MySQL 8, I suggest using CTE's to remove redundant filter expressions (and eventually to gain some further speedup) like so:

```sql
WITH
    FILTERED_PRODUCTS AS (
        SELECT
            p.*
        FROM
            products p
        WHERE
              (match(p.name) against('+saucony +"ride iso 2" -women* -kid* -junior*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
          AND p.is_custom = 0
    ),
    FILTERED_PRODUCT_PRICES AS (
        SELECT
            MIN(p.display_price) MIN_PRICE,
            p.datafeed_id
        FROM
            FILTERED_PRODUCTS p
        GROUP BY p.datafeed_id
    )
SELECT
    p.datafeed_id,
    p.display_price,
    p.*
FROM
    FILTERED_PRODUCTS p
        JOIN
        FILTERED_PRODUCT_PRICES f ON
                p.display_price = f.MIN_PRICE
                AND p.datafeed_id = f.datafeed_id

GROUP BY p.datafeed_id
ORDER BY p.datafeed_id
```

I feel the last `GROUP BY` statement should be replaced by a more deterministic selection, even if it requires a additional subselect statement.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I found a way faster query

I'm posting it as an answer in case anybody needs it

```
SELECT     p.*
FROM       products AS p
INNER JOIN
           (
                    SELECT   p.datafeed_id,
                             Min(p.display_price) AS minprice
                    FROM     products             AS p
                    WHERE      (MATCH(p.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2"' IN boolean mode))
                    AND      p.is_custom = 0
                    GROUP BY p.datafeed_id ) AS p2
ON         (
                      p.display_price = p2.minprice
           AND        p.datafeed_id = p2.datafeed_id)
WHERE      (
                      MATCH(p.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2"' IN boolean mode))
AND        p.is_custom = 0
GROUP BY   p.datafeed_id
LIMIT      50
```

Comment: Next time, please provide a `mcve` . Your question didn't mentioned the `datafeeds` table and anything about the table meta structure.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.

I edited the answer to remove references to the datafeed table.

It's not really relevant to the SELECT (it's needed to get the datafeed name/logo etc).

Do you see my solution as effective?

The table has indexes on id/mykey/name/display_price /datafeed_id/category_id

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the join by using a window function.  Instead of first finding the minimums and then scan the table again to find the rows with the minimum value, by using a window function you need only scan the table once.  The query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT a.*,
         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY datafeed_id ORDER BY display_price) AS r
  FROM products a
  WHERE is_custom = 0 
    AND MATCH(name) AGAINST ('+saucony +"ride iso 2" -women* -kid* -junior*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) AS p
WHERE r = 1
ORDER BY datafeed_id
LIMIT 50;
```

(Window functions are only available in MySQL 8.0)

Comment: thank you.
at the moment the server is mysql 5.7.
I will upgrade and test your version